# How to make Mysql use index for selects with unary condition in 'where'

Tags: mysql

I have a query in Ruby on Rails application with a strange unary condition in where:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (active)  ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I didn't even know that such conditions are allowed and can't find documentation describing this syntax anywhere. Experiments show that this is some kind of an equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE active!=0  ORDER BY id DESC;
```

The problem is that Mysql uses index for the second variany only:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (active)  ORDER BY id DESC;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 560646 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+


mysql> explain SELECT * FROM messages WHERE active!=0  ORDER BY id DESC;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+------------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys    | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+------------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages | range | active_id,active | active | 2       | NULL | 1394 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+------------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
```

I can't change the query text since, as it was explained to me, the application generates queries on the fly and they are not stored anywhere. So my questions are:

1. Do I understand the meaning of this unary clause correctly?
2. Why such queries don't use indices?
3. Is it possible to make Mysql to use an index on this one without changing the query text?

Comment: You are right about the point 1. What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Mysql version is 5.6.34.

Comment: [db-fiddle for mysql-8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afaac6257326187a6e93de8fc5fc0db7)

Comment: btw haven't searched bugs.mysql.com. I'd suggest raising a bug report if cannot find and existing bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are right, both clauses should have the same result (assuming an int type).
2. The server code doesn't appear to recognise the equivalence. Testing on MySQL-8.0 and the same query plan exists. MariaDB-10.2, and 10.3 appear to both use an index for both cases.
3. No.

If the range of values in `active` is 0 or 1; A `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE active=1  ORDER BY id DESC` query will be able to use the index for ordering (hence no `filesort`), if `id` is a primary key;